# ASP.NET MVC 4 custom attributes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with one property:
public string UserName {get;set;}

Im my database i have a list of attributes that I need to add to this property. I get a dictionary of attribute name and attribute value from the database based on the property name ("UserName")
How can I add these custom attributes to the property?

Thanks,
Kruvi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Dictionary` like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("UserID", "1");
dict.Add("UserName", "Jon");
dict.Add("Age", "58");
```

If you want to get the value of the Item in dictionary with `Keyname` `"UserName"`, You can use get it like this

```
   if (dict.ContainsKey("UserName"))
   {
       string userName=dict["UserName"];
   }
```

Why are you loading the data from your database to a Dictionary ? Why not load directly to your domain object ?